How to use Ansible to add a comment line to each line of a file
I am using ansible-playbook to edit a disa stig playbook. Upon initial run, it just bricks the server (RHEL 8). I want to comment out each line of the file which is over 20K lines. Then I can uncomment section by section until we figure out what is bricking my server(s).
I have added lines to files, and removed lines from files using ansible playbook, but I have not added a comment line to each line of a file. Does anyone have a snipet I can use to do that. I just need to add the # to the beginning of each line of the file.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

You could do this using the replace module, which might look something like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: example.txt
        regexp: '^'
        replace: '#'

But you could also just run sed:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - command: "sed -i 's/^/#/' example.txt"

As written, both of the above tasks are not idempotent: they will re-comment every line each time they run. Both could be made idempotent, provided that the file you're modifying doesn't already have commented lines in it.
We could make the replace version idempotent like this:
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: example.txt
        regexp: '^(?!#)'
        replace: '#'

And the sed version like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - command: "sed -i '/^#/!s/^/#/' example.txt"

The difference between these two tasks is that the sed version will always show a changed status, while the replace version will show an ok status if it doesn't make any changes to the file.
